# Через сколько ios 10-12 выгружает приложение из памяти после сворачивания?

Tags: ios

Во времена телефонов iphone 4s и ios5-6, приложение убивалось через 10 минут после сворачивания.

**Как работают современный версии ios 10-12 с устройствами выше iPhone5s?**

Складывается ощущение что приложения не выгружаются совсем, отсюда возникает второй вопрос.

**Насколько правильно делать счетчик запусков приложения в методе didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?**